# Circumflex sign above x in Latex

Tags: math-mode, sharelatex

I tried to do following formula in ShareLatex:

[image]

This is way I have done so far:

```
{\LARGE$\mathlarger{x_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=i-n+1}^{i} z_j }$}
```

And the output is like this:

[image]

And I tried to add the `^` (circumflex) sign above the *`x`* like this:

```
{\LARGE$\mathlarger{\^{x}_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=i-n+1}^{i} z_j }$}
```

But the output look like this:

[image]

**My Question:**

1. Why the arrow with line appears? and how can I make the *`x`* looks like the original formula?
2. How can I make the sum sign bigger and the formula under sum smaller like the original?

**Note:**

The packages I have added in general in my document:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{relsize}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\^` is a text accent, you want `\hat`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is to display the equation… in display. If you want you can resize it with `mathlarger`, but I personally don't like it.

You could also exploit the `mathtools` package facilities to compress the formula. Here is what I propose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,relsize,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\hat{x}_{i}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}z_{j}
\]
\[
 \hat{x}_{i}=\frac{1}{n}\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}}z_{j}
\]
\[
 \hat{x}_{i}=(1/n) \smashoperator{\sum_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}}z_{j}
\]
\[
\hat{x}_{i}=\frac{1}{n}\mathlarger{\sum}_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}z_{j}
\]
\[
\hat{x}_{i}=\frac{1}{n} \smashoperator[r]{\mathop{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}}z_{j}
\]
 \[
\hat{x}_{i}= (1/n) \smashoperator{\mathop{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{ j=i-n+1}^{i}}z_{j}
\]
\end{document}
```

the first three use normal summation, the latter use the enlarged one.

In each set, the first summation is set with its natural width, the second removes some space on the right of it, the third compresses it all (but you have to use the `1/n` form of fraction for it to be acceptable

[image]

Comment: +1. And off-topic: this is a situation where `mathtools` and `\smashoperator` or `\mathclap` would give an even better looking result :-)

Comment: @hooy I tried but I'm not convinced: the `1/n` comes too close to the subscript imo

Comment: Yes, but `\smashoperator[r]` may work. At least then the `z_{j}` will be closer to the sum symbol. Or one can toy around with manual spaces between the `1/n` and the sum symbol, or with struts in the limit etc.

Comment: If you replaced `\frac{1}{n}` with `(1/n)`, `\smashoperator` and `\mathclap` could be used without incurring the risk of (typographic) collisions.

Comment: might be useful https://da.sharelatex.com/blog/2012/06/12/mathtools-for-beautiful-math.html, http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf

Comment: @Mico I will try and add something, if I can, as soon as I come home from work

Comment: You should include the parentheses around `(1/n)`, or else it may be interpreted as `1/(n Σz_{j})`.